# Laplace transform of Heaviside step function of free variables

Tags: differential-equations, integral-transforms

In *A First Course in Differential Equations with Modeling Applications, Tenth Edition* (Zill, 2013) it's stated that if

$$\mathcal{U(x)}= \begin{cases} 
      0,\;x < 0 \\
      1,\;x \geq 0
   \end{cases}
\;$$

then

$$\mathcal{L}\{\;\mathcal{U}(t-a)\;\}=\frac{1}{s}e^{-as}.$$

Now $f(t)=\mathcal{U}(t-a)-\mathcal{U}(t-b)$, so I expect that $\mathcal{L}\{f\left(t\right)\}=\frac{1}{s}\left(e^{-as}-e^{-bs}\right)$ when $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers; but

```
f = UnitStep[t - a] - UnitStep[t - b];
LaplaceTransform[f, t, s]
```

yields
$\frac{e^{-a s} \theta (a)+\theta (-a)}{s}-\frac{e^{-b s} \theta (b)+\theta (-b)}{s}$ (where $\theta$ is `UnitStep`),
though

```
LaplaceTransform[f/.{a->1, b->2}, t, s]
```

yields $\frac{e^{-s}}{s}-\frac{e^{-2 s}}{s}$ as I expect.

How can I restrict $a$ and $b$ when I apply the transform so that I get the general solution without `UnitStep`? I tried changing `f` to a boolean expression (e.g. $f\;\&\&\;a\in \mathbb{R}\;\&\&\;a\geq0\ldots$), but that didn't produce any useful output.

Comment: You may just specify the domain: `Simplify[LaplaceTransform[f, t, s], Element[{a, b}, PositiveReals]]`.

Comment: Yes that's perfect thank you @Alx, I didn't know that Simplify would be the place to do that. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the domain of a function when applying an operator use [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) with or without [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) (from [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220975/laplace-transform-of-heaviside-step-function-of-free-variables#comment562562_220975)):

- `Simplify[LaplaceTransform[f, t, s], Element[{a, b}, PositiveReals]]`
- `Assuming[Element[{a, b}, PositiveReals], Simplify[LaplaceTransform[f, t, s]]]`

Here `Element[{a, b}, PositiveReals]` can be written as `{a, b} \[Element] PositiveReals`, or as $\{a,b\}\in \mathbb{R}_{>\, 0}$ by typing

```
{a,b} [ESC]elem[ESC] PositiveReals[Ctrl-Shift-Left][Ctrl-Shift-Return]
```

where `[Ctrl-Shift-Return]` is [Evaluate in Place](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/EvaluateInPlace.html).